# JQuery component id contain [ ]

Tags: jquery

Hw can i select component with id, which contain [ ] symbols?

for example:

```
<div id=divtables[COURSE_SUBJECTS][141][TITLE]>gg</div>
```

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] symbols aren't valid id characters. If you want to try it out, use a double backslash:

```
$("#divtables\\[COURSE_SUBJECTS\\]")
```

Comment: thx, this is spec symbol for jQuery/
Another specsymbols:
#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid id according to W3C:

> Naming rules:
>
> Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
>
> Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z),
> digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
> underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
> periods (".")
>
> Values are case-sensitive

This basically says that you should not have `[]` in an id. I would strongly suggest you following the standards.

Comment: Does HTML5 still have this restriction?  I'm unable to find it, spec doesn't mention it like it does in HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2):

As per [w3c standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) you cannot use [] for an ID property in HTML.
That means you can only use the following characters for ID property.

```
 Letters ([A-Za-z])
 digits ([0-9])
 hyphens ("-")
 underscores ("_")
 colons (":")
 periods (".").
```

Comment: It should be noted this is for HTML4, I don't think HTML5 has such a restriction: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Nick Craver Yes, You are correct. There is no restrictions in html5 except it cant be null.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape them, like this:

```
$("#divtables\\[COURSE_SUBJECTS\\]\\[141\\]\\[TITLE\\]")
```

[There's a full FAQ/how-to on the escaping topic here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F), this works for any selector type, though you should have different IDs values possible (ones that don't result in invalid HTML mainly).  I know this isn't always the case, e.g. content generated by another system, the solution above *works* for this, but it's not the best solution, replacing any invalid characters would be best, I'd suggest this:

```
<div id="divtables-COURSE_SUBJECTS-141-TITLE">gg</div>
```

Then your selector doesn't need any tricks, it's just:

```
$("#divtables-COURSE_SUBJECTS-141-TITLE")
```