# how do i represent document.getElementById('page1:form2:amount') in jquery?

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

How can I represent

```
document.getElementById('page1:form2:amount')
```

in jQuery

I know I can use

```
$('#amount')
```

to access the id amount. 
The id amount is an `<apex:inputText/>` type which is how an input text is represented in the Visualforce page. To access this id I would need to use the hierarchy of page->form->id.

Thanks

Prady

Update: Code used in Visualforce page.

```
<apex:page controller="acontroller" id="page1">
  <apex:form id="form2">
    <apex:inputText value="{!amt}" id="amount" onchange="calenddate();"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery component id contain \[ \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013838/jquery-component-id-contain)

Comment: @Kenny, The id doesnt contain any special characters, just i need to call the id with pagename:formname:id

Comment: Can you add an example of the html?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about `'page1:form2:amount'` :-/

Comment: @reigel and @Jimmy i added the code hopefully this makes it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is get the form instance and find all the input type text(not necessary) and get the id attribute from the instance

```
<form id="myform">
        <input type="text" value="hello1" id="1">
            <input type="text" value="hello2" id="2">
            <input type="text" value="hello3" id="3">
            <input type="text" value="hello4" id="4">
</form>



$('#myform > input[type="text"]').each(function(key,value){
         $(value).attr('id');
})
```

and as of your server-side code, anyways it will be converted to standard HTML format on client side and javascript will read the final HTML tags only. so go to source and find what exactly is the replacment for  and then use that tag to be searched in the jQuery function

Comment: you are right.. id was created as page1:form2:amount in the generated html. So i can now do whatever i want using the id

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit late, but another way to do it would be with the jQuery Attribute ends with selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

You know that the id that you put in the apex code is always the last one on the generated id.  So you can do `jQuery('[id$="amount"]')`.

What this does is select the part of the id attribute that ends with amount (you need to be certain there are no other fields end this way).

This has worked perfect for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass selectors as if you would write them with CSS.

```
$('#page1 #form2 #amount').doSomething(...)
```

As selectors in jQ work from right to left it would mean: find element with id #amount which have a parent with id #form2 and make sure that they have a parent #page1 and only then do something.

more on jQ selectors @[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I thought this should do the trick, but the id generated from the server side was different